# HttpWebResponse "SeeOther" StatusCode returned instead of 404

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-404, httpwebresponse

I'm doing a web request which should return a 404 status code, as the URL does not exist, but it's returning a 303 (SeeOther) status instead. If I look at the URL it's returning as the redirect URL it is:

http://guide.opendns.com/?url=www.googuaoeuaoeu23p2le.com

Does anyone know how I can prevent this and see the raw 404 without the openDNS redirect hijacking it?

My code:

```
        // create the HttpWebRequest object
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("www.googuaoeuaoeu23p2le.com") as HttpWebRequest;

        // don't allow redirect
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        request.Method = "GET";
        request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.SendChunked = false;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.UserAgent = "NetMonitor";

        // set the timeout
        request.Timeout = 5000;

            // get the data as an HttpWebResponse object
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            // convert the data into a string (assumes that we are requesting text)
            StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            // get HTML from the response
            string responseHTML = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

            // close the response reader
            responseReader.Close();

            // at this point we successfully got a response and just need to determine what type -- get status code
            HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.StatusCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use OpenDNS? it's a flippant answer, but it's the downside to using OpenDNS. They never return host not found necessary for a webclient to detect a 404.

Although, if you're getting a response from OpenDNS, that means that your client can't find the server. The 404 would come from the server once you connected to it & it couldn't find the resource you requested.

You would need to change your code to do a DNS lookup first - look in System.Net for the dnslookup class - and return 404 if the lookup failed.

What's actually happening right now is:

- your webclient does an dns lookup on the provided hostname
- the dns lookup fails
- OpenDNS intercepts the failure and returns the IP address of their servers
- their servers then return a search response for your initial hostname along with the continuation code.

What you need to happen are the following scenerios

- you do a dns lookup on the hostname
- the host does not exist so you return 404

or

- you do a dns lookup on the hostname
- the host exists so you make the request
- the host cannot find the path requested so returns 404
- you return 404

or

- you do a dns lookup on the hostname
- the host exists so you make the request
- the path exists and the hosts returns the data requested.
- you return this to your client

Comment: Do you have any idea how to disable OpenDNS? Is it a service of my DNS Provider? I have no idea.

Comment: it's a network setting, either set on the machine or by the network your machine is connected to. But like I said, to validate the hostname you're connecting to, you need to do a dns lookup first. this will pass or fail & then you can return 404.

Comment: I don't think the DNS lookup will cut it, because it's more than just a domain -- it could be a deep URL, js file, etc.

Comment: you need to establish the host exists though before you can query for the path though. if the host doesn't exist, you can't get a reply back. I've added an extra explanation of what's happening. hopefully that will help.